# PowerShell Exit inside SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-pipelines

I'm executing this query inside a PowerShellscript.

The thing is that I need to exit this query (inside a foreach) if the case enters the ELSE condition at least once

```
 try {
     $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "MY SELECT QUERY GOES HERE AND WORKS
                                    IF @Count >= $Count
                                        PRINT 'OK ' 
                                    ELSE   
                                        PRINT 'NOOK ' (And exit 1 to throw error)
                                    " }
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What if you process each element instead of collecting all, instead of assigning to `$result`, you could do `Invoke-SqlCmd ..... | ForEach-Object { if (....unexpected...) { do something }` that might work. Unless I'm misunderstanding the issue

Comment: SQL Server has `RETURN` statement. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: You can also simply run something like `SELECT 1`

Comment: I don't believe there's a (logical) way to capture `PRINT` output from `Invoke-Sqlcmd` so you wouldn't be able to react to it. (Yes, I'm aware you can `-Verbose` it and redirect `4>&1` to capture the output, but it loses useful information.) In .NET Framework/Core you can hook the `SqlClient.InfoMessage` event and assume that events with `SqlError.Number==0` are `PRINT` output. Perhaps you could just [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sq) from the T-SQL statement and use normal PowerShell exception handling from there?